# How do I merge two CSV files based on field and keep same number of attributes on each record?

Tags: python, csv, merge

I am attempting to merge two CSV files based on a specific field in each file.

**file1.csv**

```
id,attr1,attr2,attr3
1,True,7,"Purple"
2,False,19.8,"Cucumber"
3,False,-0.5,"A string with a comma, because it has one"
4,True,2,"Nope"
5,True,4.0,"Tuesday"
6,False,1,"Failure"
```

**file2.csv**

```
id,attr4,attr5,attr6
2,"python",500000.12,False
5,"program",3,True
3,"Another string",-5,False
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file2.csv','r') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f2)
    fields2 = next(reader,None) # Skip headers
    dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in reader}

with open('file1.csv','r') as f1:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    fields1 = next(reader,None) # Skip headers
    dict1 = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in reader)

result = OrderedDict()
for d in (dict1, dict2):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)

with open('merged.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in result.iteritems():
        w.writerow([key] + value)
```

I get output like this, which merges appropriately, but does not have the same number of attributes for all rows:

```
1,True,7,Purple
2,False,19.8,Cucumber,python,500000.12,False
3,False,-0.5,"A string with a comma, because it has one",Another string,-5,False
4,True,2,Nope
5,True,4.0,Tuesday,program,3,True
6,False,1,Failure
```

`file2` will not have a record for every `id` in `file1`. I'd like the output to have empty fields from `file2` in the merged file. For example, `id` 1 would look like this:

```
1,True,7,Purple,,,
```

How can I add the empty fields to records that don't have data in `file2` so that all of my records in the merged CSV have the same number of attributes?

Comment: Do you also want the header line to be `id,attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4,attr5,attr6`?

Comment: @s16h Yes. I didn't include that code in my example code. I have that working already though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we're not using `pandas`, I'd refactor to something like

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

filenames = "file1.csv", "file2.csv"
data = OrderedDict()
fieldnames = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp: # python 2
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
        fieldnames.extend(reader.fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            data.setdefault(row["id"], {}).update(row)

fieldnames = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(fieldnames))
with open("merged.csv", "wb") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in data.itervalues():
        writer.writerow([row.get(field, '') for field in fieldnames])
```

which gives

```
id,attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4,attr5,attr6
1,True,7,Purple,,,
2,False,19.8,Cucumber,python,500000.12,False
3,False,-0.5,"A string with a comma, because it has one",Another string,-5,False
4,True,2,Nope,,,
5,True,4.0,Tuesday,program,3,True
6,False,1,Failure,,,
```

For comparison, the `pandas` equivalent would be something like

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="outer").fillna("")
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

which is much simpler to my eyes, and means you can spend more time dealing with your data and less time reinventing wheels.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do this:

```
import pandas

csv1 = pandas.read_csv('filea1.csv')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('file2.csv')
merged = csv1.merge(csv2, on='id')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

I haven't tested this yet but it should put you on the right track until I can try it out. The code is quite self-explanatory; first you import the `pandas` library so that you can use it. Then using `pandas.read_csv` you read the 2 csv files and use the `merge` method to merge them. The `on` parameter specifies which column should be used as the "key". Finally, the merged csv is written to `output.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Use dict of dict then update it. Like this:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file2.csv','r') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f2)
    lines2 = list(reader)

with open('file1.csv','r') as f1:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    lines1 = list(reader)

dict1 = {row[0]: dict(zip(lines1[0][1:], row[1:])) for row in lines1[1:]}
dict2 = {row[0]: dict(zip(lines2[0][1:], row[1:])) for row in lines2[1:]}

#merge
updatedDict = OrderedDict()
mergedAttrs = OrderedDict.fromkeys(lines1[0][1:] + lines2[0][1:], "?")
for id, attrs in dict1.iteritems():
    d = mergedAttrs.copy()
    d.update(attrs)
    updatedDict[id] = d

for id, attrs in dict2.iteritems():
    updatedDict[id].update(attrs)

#out
with open('merged.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for id, rest in sorted(updatedDict.iteritems()):
        w.writerow([id] + rest.values())
```